# how to fetch multiple rows with same field value from a mysql database using php

Tags: mysql, php

```
|touser| fromuser |  msg  |
|  A   |    B     | hi    |
|  A   |    B     | hello |
|  C   |    D     | bye   |
|  C   |    E     | hey   |
```

when i use following query in mysql workbench it shows the desired result that is all the rows with given name:

```
select * from db.table1 where touser in ('A');
```

output:

```
|touser| fromuser |  msg  |
|  A   |    B     | hi    |
|  A   |    B     | hello |
```

but when i pass query from php commands the resultant array contains only first record

```
<?php
 //connection establishing commands
 $sql="select * from db.table1 where touser in ('A')";

 $result=mysqli_query($link, $sql);

 $data=mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_NUM);

 print_r($data);

 //other stuff;
 ?>
```

output:

```
    Array ( [0] => A [1] => B [2] => Hi )
```

am I missing something in the php commands?

Comment: dont use mysqli functions now...it is not recommanded nowadays...

Comment: @shwetdalal are you saying to use PDO?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're PHP is simply returning the first row of the MySQL result set.

You'll want to replace `$data=mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_NUM);`

with

```
while ($data = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_NUM)) {
    print_r($data);
}
```

Which will iterate over each row of the result set. In other words, the mysqli_fetch_array function doesn't fetch the entire result set as an array, it simply returns a single row, and then moves the row "pointer" to the next row.